# How to display a specific popup when the user chooses its price range as well as selecting specific buttons via JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a website for my project where the user can select the product price range and select its components. Therefore, after the user selects their preferences and submits them, it displays a popup where the user can see all the listed details.

So for instance, if the user selects the price $2000 and the item x and item z the related products would be displayed to the user in a popup.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3049ab8192.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</head>
<body>


     <!--- slider section -->
     <div class="main__1">
        <div class="slide__options__container">
            <div class="wrapper">
                  <div class="price-input">
                    <div class="field">
                      <span>Min</span>
                      <input type="number" class="input-min" value="2500">
                    </div>
                    <div class="separator">-</div>
                    <div class="field">
                      <span>Max</span>
                      <input type="number" class="input-max" value="7500">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="slider">
                    <div class="progress"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="range-input">
                    <input type="range" class="range-min" min="0" max="10000" value="2500" step="100">
                    <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" max="10000" value="7500" step="100">
                  </div>
    
                </div>

                <h2> pick item 1</h2>
                <div class="mainbtn__1">
                    <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="x">item x</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="y">item y</button>
                </div>

                <h2> pick item 2 </h2>
                <div class="mainbtn__2">
                    <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="e">item e</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="z">item z</button>
                </div>

                <div class="popup__container">
                    <button type="submit" class="popup__btn" onclick="open__Popup()" >submit</button>
                    
                    <!-- FIRST popup page -->
                    <div class="popup" id="popup" >
                        <table class="table__1" id="tb_1">
                            <tr>
                                <td>item 1</td>
                                <td>x</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>item 2</td>
                                <td>e</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Price</td>
                                <td>$2000</td>
                              </tr>

                        </table>"
                        <button type="button" class="close__btn" onclick="close__Popup()">Close</button>
                    </div>


                    <!-- second popup page -->
                    <div class="popup__2" id="popup__2">
                        <table class="table__2" id="tb_2">
                            <tr>
                                <td>item 1</td>
                                <td>y</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>item 2</td>
                                <td>z</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                <td>Price</td>
                                <td>$3000</td>
                              </tr>

                        </table>"
                        <button type="button" class="close__btn" onclick="close__Popup()">Close</button>

                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
     </div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Css:

```
/* buttons options section*/


.special__1{
  background-color: #4837ff;
}


.special__2{
  background-color: #4837ff;
}



/*  pop up page    */

.popup__container{
  position: relative;
  text-align:center;
}

  
.popup{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.open-Popup{
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.table__1{
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
   border: 1px solid #acacac;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


.close__btn{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  background: hsla(204, 100%, 15%, 0.286);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

/*   second pop up page   */

.popup__2{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.open-Popup{
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.table__2{
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
td, th {
   border: 1px solid #acacac;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


.close__btn{
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 80px;

}
```

js:

```
//slider
const rangeInput = document.querySelectorAll(".range-input input"),
  priceInput = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input input"),
  range = document.querySelector(".slider .progress");
let priceGap = 1000;

priceInput.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    let minPrice = parseInt(priceInput[0].value),
      maxPrice = parseInt(priceInput[1].value);

    if (maxPrice - minPrice >= priceGap && maxPrice <= rangeInput[1].max) {
      if (e.target.className === "input-min") {
        rangeInput[0].value = minPrice;
        range.style.left = (minPrice / rangeInput[0].max) * 100 + "%";
      } else {
        rangeInput[1].value = maxPrice;
        range.style.right = 100 - (maxPrice / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
      }
    }
  });
});

rangeInput.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput[0].value),
      maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput[1].value);

    if (maxVal - minVal < priceGap) {
      if (e.target.className === "range-min") {
        rangeInput[0].value = maxVal - priceGap;
      } else {
        rangeInput[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
      }
    } else {
      priceInput[0].value = minVal;
      priceInput[1].value = maxVal;
      range.style.left = (minVal / rangeInput[0].max) * 100 + "%";
      range.style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
    }
  });
});



//choices buttons

const mainbtnEL_1 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__001");

mainbtnEL_1.forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.special__1')?.classList.remove('special__1');

    btnEl.classList.add('special__1');
  });
});


const mainbtnEL_2 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__002");

mainbtnEL_2.forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.special__2')?.classList.remove('special__2');

    btnEl.classList.add('special__2');
  });
});



//pop up

let popup = document.getElementById("popup");




function open__Popup() {
  
  popup.classList.add('open-Popup');
}
function close__Popup() {
  popup.classList.remove('open-Popup');
}


let popup__2 = document.getElementById("popup__2");

function open__Popup() {
  popup__2.classList.add('open-Popup');
}
function close__Popup() {
  popup__2.classList.remove('open-Popup');
}
```

So far, I've tried different js codes but it's not working, all I'm getting is the same popup regardless of the price and button selection.
I would genuinely appreciate it if anyone could help me here sort this out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the same popup was triggered is because you had given the same function name for both open popup functions, i.e - for popup one, you have defined `function open__Popup()` and for popup two, you have defined `function open__Popup()`.

This is why, js was triggering the second function since that was the latest one.

I have modified your code and added jQuery as a dependency. I'm not sure whether this is the right requirement but what I have done is that I have removed the need for defining 2 different popups and instead declared only one. When you click submit, I read the values that you have selected and then I replace the text inside the table with the values that the user has selected. Have a look at the below code.

```js
//slider
const rangeInput = document.querySelectorAll(".range-input input"),
  priceInput = document.querySelectorAll(".price-input input"),
  range = document.querySelector(".slider .progress");
let priceGap = 1000;

priceInput.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    let minPrice = parseInt(priceInput[0].value),
      maxPrice = parseInt(priceInput[1].value);

    if (maxPrice - minPrice >= priceGap && maxPrice <= rangeInput[1].max) {
      if (e.target.className === "input-min") {
        rangeInput[0].value = minPrice;
        range.style.left = (minPrice / rangeInput[0].max) * 100 + "%";
      } else {
        rangeInput[1].value = maxPrice;
        range.style.right = 100 - (maxPrice / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
      }
    }
  });
});

rangeInput.forEach((input) => {
  input.addEventListener("input", (e) => {
    let minVal = parseInt(rangeInput[0].value),
      maxVal = parseInt(rangeInput[1].value);

    if (maxVal - minVal < priceGap) {
      if (e.target.className === "range-min") {
        rangeInput[0].value = maxVal - priceGap;
      } else {
        rangeInput[1].value = minVal + priceGap;
      }
    } else {
      priceInput[0].value = minVal;
      priceInput[1].value = maxVal;
      range.style.left = (minVal / rangeInput[0].max) * 100 + "%";
      range.style.right = 100 - (maxVal / rangeInput[1].max) * 100 + "%";
    }
  });
});



//choices buttons

const mainbtnEL_1 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__001");

mainbtnEL_1.forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.special__1')?.classList.remove('special__1');

    btnEl.classList.add('special__1');
  });
});


const mainbtnEL_2 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn__002");

mainbtnEL_2.forEach(btnEl => {
  btnEl.addEventListener("click", () => {
    document.querySelector('.special__2')?.classList.remove('special__2');

    btnEl.classList.add('special__2');
  });
});



//pop up

let popup = document.getElementById("popup");




function open__Popup() {
  $('#item1Container').text($('.special__1').text());
  
  $('#item2Container').text($('.special__2').text());
  
  popup.classList.add('open-Popup');
}
function close__Popup() {
  popup.classList.remove('open-Popup');
}


let popup__2 = document.getElementById("popup__2");

function open__Popup2() {
  popup__2.classList.add('open-Popup');
}
function close__Popup2() {
  popup__2.classList.remove('open-Popup');
}
```

```css
/* buttons options section*/


.special__1 {
  background-color: #4837ff;
}


.special__2 {
  background-color: #4837ff;
}



/*  pop up page    */

.popup__container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}


.popup {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.open-Popup {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.table__1 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


.close__btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 80px;
  background: hsla(204, 100%, 15%, 0.286);
  color: #fff;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);

}

/*   second pop up page   */

.popup__2 {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  width: 800px;
  max-width: 800px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 6px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(0.1);
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 0 30px 30px;
  color: #333;
  align-items: center;
  justify-self: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50vh;
  z-index: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: transform 0.4s ease;
}

.open-Popup {
  visibility: visible;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}

.table__2 {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #acacac;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #dddddd;
}


.close__btn {
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  left: 80px;

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title> test </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/3049ab8192.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  </head>

  <body>


    <!--- slider section -->
    <div class="main__1">
      <div class="slide__options__container">
        <div class="wrapper">
          <div class="price-input">
            <div class="field">
              <span>Min</span>
              <input type="number" class="input-min" value="2500">
            </div>
            <div class="separator">-</div>
            <div class="field">
              <span>Max</span>
              <input type="number" class="input-max" value="7500">
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="slider">
            <div class="progress"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="range-input">
            <input type="range" class="range-min" min="0" max="10000" value="2500" step="100">
            <input type="range" class="range-max" min="0" max="10000" value="7500" step="100">
          </div>

        </div>

        <h2> pick item 1</h2>
        <div class="mainbtn__1">
          <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="x">item x</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn__001" id="y">item y</button>
        </div>

        <h2> pick item 2 </h2>
        <div class="mainbtn__2">
          <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="e">item e</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn__002" id="z">item z</button>
        </div>

        <div class="popup__container">
          <button type="submit" class="popup__btn" onclick="open__Popup()">submit</button>

          <!-- FIRST popup page -->
          <div class="popup" id="popup">
            <table class="table__1" id="tb_1">
              <tr>
                <td>item 1</td>
                <td id="item1Container"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>item 2</td>
                <td id="item2Container"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>Price</td>
                <td>$2000</td>
              </tr>

            </table>"
            <button type="button" class="close__btn" onclick="close__Popup()">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>



  </body>

</html>
```